# Magento 2 Shopping Cart Buy 2 products, get 25% off on cheapest one

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

Can we make this rule Buy 2 products, get 25% off on cheapest one without third party extension?

Comment: This is not default you will to create plugin, can be done via observer

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any hints or tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an observer which will be fired in the event:-

```
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost
```

Then you override the controller `CouponPost` that is executing for checkout cart. Now using this code in your observer:-

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        //Your algorithm here
    }
```

You will need to use preference for overriding the controller with `after`.

I am not 100% confident of the workflow but this is where you can start from.